# What does this code snippet do exactly?

Tags: c++, k-means

```
int max = 0, id = 0;
int indx= 0;

vector<int> clusters(k,0);

for (size_t i = 0; i < bestLabels.size(); i++)
{
    id = bestLabels[i];
    clusters[id]++;

    if (clusters[id] > max)
    {
        max = clusters[id];
        indx = id;
    }
}
```

This code calculates for the largest cluster through K-Means Clustering but i don't quite understand how "clusters[id]++;" and "cluster[id]" work. What do they do exactly? Can anyone please give a detailed explanation on the process happening inside the for loop? Any help would be highly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate : [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](http://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/327083)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following line:

`vector<int> clusters(k,0);`

Defines a random-access collection of `k` total integers each with an initial value of 0. `clusters[id]` accesses the integer value stored at index `id` in the vector. `clusters[id]++` increments the integer value stored at index `id`. This works because `operator []` on a vector returns a reference to the indexed item, allowing modification.

Comment: oh i see. it makes more sense to me now. i just got confused because of the "clusters" variable having two parameters and increments it with the variable "id". Thank you, Mikel!

Answer (score 0):

The for loop iterates through the labels in `bestLabels` and scores them based on how often they appear (`clusters[id]++` - this part increases the score, or frequency). It also keep track of the most frequent label - that's what the clause of the `if (clusters[id] > max)` condition does.

Comment: Thank you for your answer too, holygeek. i guess i was more confused with the vectors<int> variable but i get it now.